# Convert String into MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, string

I have this string in PHP:

```
$str = 1,3,6,5
```

These numbers can change and the length of the set can change to more or less than four. I want to convert to a MySQL query like this in PHP:

```
$qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE id = 1 or id = 3 or id = 6 or id = 5")
```

It should be easy, but I don't know how to do it.

I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: preg_split("/,/", $str);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `IN`.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN ($str)");
```

Make sure `$str` is validated first to prevent sql injection.

Comment: Would having a loop casting all values to int be sufficient ?